# iPython Notebook in VSCode via a Pipenv shell: two questions on environments not aligning

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython, conda, pipenv

I am trying to use VSCode's (I don't need to  but figured I'd try this out) new-ish notebook functionality.  Two things are happening:

**<got rid of question #1>**

2. Notebook doesn't seem to have access to the environment variables available in the shell from which I launched the VSCode notebook.

**<steps for #2 below>**

### Update:

I got rid of the conda environment to simplify things.  Just using pipenv now.  This allowed me to make sense of where my modules were so the Pandas issue is "fixed".  That said, still not able to get the environment variables in VSCode.

Steps:

- Hop into `pipenv shell`
- Export environment variables
- Check it: `env | grep <env_var>`
- Hop into Python interactive shell (no args) -- runs the venv `bin/python`
- `import os` and `os.environ.get("<env_var>")` -- access to env_var verified
- exit Python shell and launch `code <notebook>`
- verify that ipykernel is installed and that the VSCode Python interpreter is using the venv Python -- verified

Any ideas?

Comment: To show environment variables in shell and get them in notebook, about your question, more details are needed like notebook and terminal error screenshots, the interpreter environment. post with screenshots instead of words

Comment: @MollyWang I don't understand what you want screenshots of?  There are no errors.  IMO words describe the situation best.  I can't even fathom what I would screenshot that wouldn't just be the commands I mentioned.